# How to call Snowflake procedure in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've got a problem with my Lambda code. It can't execute the procedure in Snowflake. What I'm doing wrong? I can't call the procedure ;(

```
import snowflake.connector
 import boto3
 import json
 import os
 
 import logging
 
 logger = logging.getLogger()
 logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
 
 def run_query(con, query):
     cursor = con.cursor();
     cursor.execute(query);
     cursor.close();
 
 # function to receive a secret value from secrets manager
 def get_secret(secret_name, region_name):
     session = boto3.session.Session()
     client = session.client(service_name="secretsmanager", region_name=region_name)
     try:
         get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)
     except Exception as e:
         raise e
     else:
         if "SecretString" in get_secret_value_response:
             secret = get_secret_value_response["SecretString"]
         else:
             secret = None
     return json.loads(secret)
 
 
 
 def lambda_handler(event, context):
     
 
     # retrieve secret_name from environment configuration
     try:
         secret_name = os.environ['secret_name']
     except KeyError:
         # default secret if not set by the infrastructure
         secret_name = "snowflake-login"
     region_name = os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION']
 
     # retreive the Secret, assign connection variables
     sf_params = get_secret(secret_name, region_name)
     try:
         PASSWORD = sf_params["sfPassword"]
         USER = sf_params["sfUser"]
         ACCOUNT = sf_params["sfAccount"]
         WAREHOUSE = sf_params["sfWarehouse"]
         DATABASE = sf_params["sfDatabase"]
         SCHEMA = sf_params["sfSchema"]
         ROLE = sf_params["sfRole"]
     except KeyError:
         error_message = "Missing connection properties in the Secret"
         raise ValueError(error_message)
 
     
 
     # connect to Snowflake
         con = snowflake.connector.connect(user=USER, account=ACCOUNT, password=PASSWORD, warehouse=WAREHOUSE,
database=DATABASE, schema=SCHEMA, role=ROLE)
         statment5 = "call MY_SCHEMA.PROCEDURE_LOAD_CSV('MY_PARAMETER')"
         run_query(con, statment5)
         logger.info(statment5)
```

Comment: you have variables for the  database and schema, but the call to use the procedure is partially qualified with `my_schema` shouldn't the variables be valid, and thus the schema not be needed, or the procedure should be fully qualified?

Comment: also what error/log you are getting?

Comment: I need to have my_schema.PROCEDURE_LOAD_CSV because I can't execute this form my_schema. It's for the job. Also I don't have any errors

Comment: Ok, so no "errors", can you please further explain "It can't execute the procedure in Snowflake"

Comment: can you execute "SELECT 1;" from the lambda and have that work? Thus all the lambda is setup and running correctly, and your snowflake connection is good and works? And therefore this might be a user permissions things? Or does the lambda not even run (which implies it has nothing to do with Snowflake) or the lambda runs, but the connection details fail and even "SELECT 1;" doesn't work? Which it could be a passing of credentials through your setup that is at fault. Can you log into snowflake directly using the credentials the lambda will work, via those can you call the procedure?